# How can I change the title of 1 HTML window from another HTML window

Tags: javascript, html

Can I do this using Javascript and if so how do I do that ?

If you have references for this it would be helpful.

Is there another way to do this without using Javascript ?

Thank you for all your help, advice & suggestions …

Comment: Do you control both pages? Are they on the same domain?

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Your title here</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    content
  </body>
</html>
```

Though your question is a bit vague, this is how the page title is set in html.

Comment: I suspect that he wants to have the JavaScript from *one* window set, or change, the `title` attribute in a *second* window.

Comment: Ahh.  'from' as in source, not as in different from.  Good call.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. Have you opened the window whose title needs to be changed? If you have, it's quite easy:

```
var theWindow = window.open('whateverUrl');
theWindow.addEventListener('load', function(evt) {
     theWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML = "Your New Title";
}, false);
```

This assumes many things: that the page opened will have a `<title>` element, that the browser supports innerHTML, and that the browser supports addEventListener, but this is just an example and can easily be fixed in those regards.

If you do not have a reference to the window, you will have to obtain one.